# Get location of a cellphone using using its GPS information

Tags: google-drive-api

I am doing a research right now, and one thing that needs to be done is to get all cellphone users at a certain area.  One way I think is possible to do this, is to get the GPS information of that cellphone user.  So is it possible to get the location of a certain cellphone users by getting its GPS information?

Thanks

Ralph

Comment: I'm trying to do the same thing for about two months , all you can say is that there http://opencellid.org/ a site with its own API where you can submit requests for cell ( I have the code if you're interested ) but have rejected because many cells have not been reported , as a site "FREE " users update cells when detected , else they existed API " secret " of google that unfortunately this is no longer possible to use, I hope to be as helpful

Comment: Thanks on this Michele, I'll look into this site.  I hope this can help me.

Comment: If you are looking for a cell to location conversion then you can also check out openmobilenetwork.org. They provide a visualization and a SPARQL endpoint for requesting crowdsourced base station and WiFi data and live data of openmobilenetwork users that are connected to the stations.

Comment: Thanks on this raspi.

Comment: what does this have to do with google drive?